# How to edit google calendar event on Android?

Tags: java, android, google-calendar-api

I want to edit event using Google Calendar API.
In example there was a code to edit calendar:

```
Entry executePatchRelativeToOriginal(Entry updated, Entry original) throws IOException {
   AtomPatchRelativeToOriginalContent content = new AtomPatchRelativeToOriginalContent();
   content.namespaceDictionary = DICTIONARY;
   content.originalEntry = original;
   content.patchedEntry = updated;
   HttpRequest request =
      requestFactory.buildPatchRequest(new GenericUrl(updated.getEditLink()), content);
   return request.execute().parseAs(updated.getClass());
```

And it works if I want edit calendar, but it don't work with edit event: I have exception:

```
09-11 17:29:13.516: WARN/System.err(15787): com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 403 Forbidden
```

Of course I have rigths to edit event. 
Moreover, the same method to delete calendar works with delete event.
Delete function:

```
public void executeDelete(Entry entry) throws IOException {
    HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildDeleteRequest(new GenericUrl(entry.getEditLink()));
    request.execute().ignore();
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! I used HTTP PUT instead of HTTP PATCH in Atom, and modified
the original event instead of create another instance of the object.

Here is a working code:

```
public EventEntry executePutUpdateEvent(EventEntry updated) throws IOException {
AtomContent content = new AtomContent();
content.namespaceDictionary = DICTIONARY;
content.entry = updated;
HttpRequest request =
    requestFactory.buildPutRequest(new GenericUrl(updated.getEditLink()), content);
return request.execute().parseAs(updated.getClass());}
```